# syntax error, unexpected end of file in php file

Tags: javascript, php, html, error-handling, syntax-error

i get a syntax error in my php file that i cant locate, but the html tag at the end is underline in my code editor, any help would be appreciated as i spent hours looking for this error and trying to locate it in my code and see where is the missing part, a bracket, a letter, or what exactly, so thank you for trying to help

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="log-it-reports2.css">
    <script src="log-it-reports.js"></script>
    <title>WearView Academy Homepage</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php


// define variables and set to empty values
$staffErr = $emailErr = $subjecterErr = $problemsiteErr = $descriptionErr= "";
$staff_name = $email = $subject = $problem_type = $description = "";


// staff name validation:
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
if (empty($_POST["staff_name"])) {
    $staffErr = "Staff Name is required";
} else {
    $staff_name = test_input($_POST["staff_name"]);
    // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z-' ]*$/",$staff_name)) {
    $staffErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
    }
}

// email validation:
if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
    $emailErr = "Email is required";
} else {
    $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
    // check if e-mail address is well-formed
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    $emailErr = "Please enter a valid email.";
    }
}

// subject validation:
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if (empty($_POST["subject"])) {
        $subjectErr = "Subject is required";
    } else {
        $subject = test_input($_POST["subject"]);
        // check if subject only contains letters and whitespace
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z-' ]*$/",$subject)) {
        $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
        }
    }
    



// problem type validation:
if (empty($_POST["problem_type"])) {
    $genderErr = "Problem type is required";
} else {
    $gender = test_input($_POST["problem_type"]);
}
}
// description validation:

if (empty($_POST["description"])) {
    $descriptionErr = "A Description is required";
} else {
    $comment = test_input($_POST["comment"]);
}

function test_input($data) {
$data = trim($data);
$data = stripslashes($data);
$data = htmlspecialchars($data);
return $data;
}


?>


    <div class= "content">

       <div class="form1">
        <form  method="GET" onsubmit=" return formValidations() " action="log-it-reports.html">
          <div class="error1" id= "errorMsg"></div>
          <div class="error" id= "errorMsg1"></div>
          <div>
          <label for="staff_name"><b>Staff Name:</b></label> 
          <input  class="field" name="staff_name" id="subject" type="text" placeholder="Staff Name"  > 
          </div><br>

          <div class="error" id= "errorMsg2"></div>
          <div>
          <label for="email"><b>Email:</b></label> 
          <input class="field" id="email1" name="email" type="email" placeholder="staff@wearview.com">  
          </div><br>
          <div class="error" id= "errorMsg3"></div>
          <div>
          <label for="subject"><b>Subject:</b></label> 
          <input  class="field" name="subject" id="subject" type="text" placeholder="Subject Title"  > 
          </div><br>

          <div class="error" id= "errorMsg4"></div>
          <div>
            <select class="field4" name="problem_type" id="problemtypes">
                <option value="">Problem Type</option>
                <option value="Hardware">Hardware</option>
                <option value="Software">Software</option>
                <option value="Software&Hardware">Software & Hardware</option>
                <option value="Other">Other</option>
              </select>
          </div><br>
          <div class="error" id= "errorMsg5"></div>
          <div>
          <textarea class="field2" id="description1" name="description" placeholder="Description goes here" name="descript" rows="15" cols="90"></textarea>
          </div>          
          
          <div>
            <button class="field3" type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
            <input type="checkbox" id="notify" name="notify" value="">
            <label for="notify">Inform me by email when issue is resolved.</label> 
        </div>
        </form>

       </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are missing a closing brace for this if statement: `if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {`

Comment: If you properly indent your code, you will be less likely to have these sorts of errors. Most programmer-friendly text editors will do it for you.

Comment: there are 2 if statements with that line, is it the first or second ? and could you tell me what it means to indent my code, im newbie here, thank you

Comment: Indenting your code means making sure that when you start off a block (such as an if statement or a while loop), you indent all lines of code within that block. Basically, when you have a {, the next line should be indented one level from where you are, and when you have a }, it should be back to the previous level of indent. See here: https://codehs.gitbooks.io/introcs/content/Programming-with-Karel/how-to-indent-your-code.html

Comment: I think it's the first if-statement.